# Need to deploy a container to multiple KIE servers running behind a load-balancer

Tags: java, deployment, drools, docker-swarm, kie

I have a docker swarm running multiple services. One of these services is a KIE server. I use Bamboo to deploy my services and I need to be able to do the same (automated deployment) for the kJar into my KIE server.
Also, I will have multiple replicas of this KIE server running so I need to be able to deploy to all of them. They will be running behind the Docker swarm load-balancer.

My question is how can I do this? The only methodology I've seen so far is to place the kJar into the .m2 directory of the server and then use a REST call to create the container.
This would work fine for a single server but not for many behind a load-balancer.

Has anyone else done this and, if so, how did you implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You keep saying "deploy", but you don't "deploy" a kjar. Have you tried hosting the kjar in a (private) maven repo and having your kie servers pull it from the repo?

Comment: Sorry, I may be using incorrect terminology. this -> "having your kie servers pull it from the repo" is pretty much what I'd like to do. The only catch is I'd like to do it from a Bamboo build. AND I will have multiple KIE servers running behind a load balancer. 
I'm using the sentryds/jboss/kie-server-showcase docker container.

Comment: I have no idea what bamboo is. Drools has built-in maven support, so if bamboo is maven based like gradle, etc, you can host a maven repo and pull from there.